# makefile returning missing separator

Tags: c, makefile

```
 testFile: test2.c
     gcc -o testFile test2.c -I.
```

Seems like a pretty basic makefile, what is going wrong? I checked all the obvious things.  The only spacing is that tab and spaces between words.

Comment: Post the entirety of the error message you're getting.

Comment: @jwodder makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Comment: It looks correct. Try simplifying it: replace the command with ':' (that is, the line should be a tab followed by a colon) and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makefiles *must* use tabs to indent the action part under a rule. Spaces will not do.

Comment: It is a tab for sure.

Comment: @PaulthePirate: Is it only a tab and nothing else? Is there no space before the rule?

Comment: Well I don't know if this made a difference but I created the file on windows, moved it to linux. It wouldn't work so then I did the tab on vim in linux and saved it. Now it works. Linux tabs != windows tabs I guess.

Comment: I suspect that on Windows you asked the editor for a tab and it gave you four spaces instead.